# How to display value of selected row to next view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array.This array loading from web service in TableView.

There are all BranchId in tableview.I want display fields of selected branchId when selected row.

e.g Selected "1234" in tableview

Open new view controller(DetailViewController) :

BranchID:1234

BranchName: ABCDEFGH

I have Branchname in web service

TableviewCodes:  http://pastie.org/8052416

How can I display selected ID's detail on new view controller ? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Xcode master-detail project template?

Comment: @Wain I can not use master-detail.It is single view

Comment: Your table view is one controller and you want to pass the selected row value to another view controller. That is master-detail...

Comment: @Wain Ok thank you but my project is single view.I said that.I can not create again via master detail.

Comment: You should clarify your question. your last comment says that your project is "single view", but the last line of your question says "How can I display selected ID's detail on new view controller". If you have a new view controller then you have more than one view. Do you mean only one view showing at a time?

Comment: @rdelmar I have only one view when select row

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways, here is one:
From your first viewController:

```
 NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:theIdYouWantToSend]
                                                     forKey:@"index"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"getID" object: dict];
```

Now from the new view controller (detailViewController), in the viewDiDLoad method:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getID:) name:@"getID" object:nil];
```

and create method:

```
-(void)getID:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*) notification.object;

}
```

You can easily get the ID from the dictionary

```
myId = [dict objectForKey:@"index"];
```

Answer (score 1):

you should modify didSelectRow method by below way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     DetailViewController *second=[[DetailViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] ;

    second.branchId = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: In the code which you have attached, modify the above method as displayed.